# Mvc 4 Forms Authentication with SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, authentication

I have some controllers that create, edit, and show details in my ASP.NET MVC 4 project. I want to authorize users who are in a SQL Server table. The table of the users is in the same database with the other users that I'm manipulating using my controllers.

I googled it, watched "MVC Forms Authentication with custom database" tutorials. I couldn't find anything to walk me properly.

Could anyone please help?

Comment: What does your authentication code look like just now? Even in its broken state, show it as its a starting point

Comment: The following will help you getting an answer: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist

Comment: I found the answer in here.This video shows you how to create MVC custom log in system:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=asKYOwd2p2w

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer in here.This video shows you how to create MVC custom log in system: youtube.com/watch?v=asKYOwd2p2w